# Thunderbird addon for email address crawler

Tags: firefox-addon, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I am looking for an addon to capture all email addresses to my address book from my Inbox.

I know EMail Address Crawler does the same;
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/email-address-crawler/

However I have the latest Thunderbird and the addon is not compatible with the latest Thunderbird.
So is there some other addon which would work with the latest Thunderbird?

Answer (score 1):

Another person seems to have picked up the slack from the original (and now unmaintained-by-the-author) code, see here:
https://nic-nac-project.org/~kaosmos/index-en.html#eac